# How can I perform OCR from the command line?

Tags: linux, ocr

I need to perform OCR on the a backend of a website on a Linux machine with printed text.

I read the other related questions here, so I tried [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), wich is considered as one of the most accurate amongst the open source ones, but it was very inaccurate for me.

I also heard about [ABBYY](http://www.ocr4linux.com/en:start), which is said to be very accurate, but it's extremely expensive. 3500€ for a usage-limited license is way too much for me.

So, here are my requirements:

- I need to be able to work on Linux with the command line.
- I need to recognize Hungarian language documents.
- I do not want to spend more than €1-2k for a licence with unlimited usage on one machine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to OCR, printed text? handwriting?

Comment: Printed text. Actually receipts.